# Number of ways of selling 5 products for 4 customers

Tags: combinatorics

A merchant has $4$ types of products. Let the number of these $4$ products are $p,q,r,s$ respectively. (p-times 1st product, q-times 2nd product, r-times 3rd product, s-times 4th product)  In how many distinct ways can he sell products to $5$ customers? Customers are undistinguishable. Species of the same product are also undistinguishable.
Each customer buys exactly one product (if it is not out of sell).
I have tried for $(p,q,r,s)$ = $(3,3,3,3)$ $=$ $40$ ways
$(p,q,r,s)$ = $(3,3,3,4)$ = $43$ ways
$(p,q,r,s)$ = $(5,5,5,5)$ = $56$ ways.
My question is: Exists general formula for number of ways for $4$ types of products and $5$  customers?

Harder task (optional): Exists general formula for number of ways for $m$ types of products and $n$ customers? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the customers actually identical, or are they distinguishable?  Are products of the same type identical, as you seem to indicate?

Comment: yes, product of the same type are identical,

Comment: Why 55 ways for $p=q=r=s=5$? I think 56 ways when $p,q,r,s\ge 5$.

Comment: yes, I am wrong. I need help to find the system and a general formula for that, thanks.

Comment: Did you try 30% OFF ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This  is  a  straightforward  application  of  the  Polya  Enumeration
Theorem. Suppose  $Z(S_n)$ is the  cycle index of the  symmetric group
given by the recurrence by Lovasz which is

$$Z(S_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n a_l Z(S_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

We obtain  by PET the following  formula for the OGF  of multisets (of
products) on $n$ slots (the customers)

$$Z(S_n)\left(\sum_{k=1}^m  X_k\right).$$

Note however  that we have a  restriction on these  multisets which is
that there are at most $q_k$  products of type $k.$ Now the generating
function

$$\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{1-X_k} 
Z(S_n)\left(\sum_{k=1}^m  X_k\right)$$

has the property that the coefficient on $X_k^q$ counts multisets with
at  most  $q$  instances  of  product  $k$  (as  opposed  to   exactly
$q$). Therefore  the end  result is (here  the square  bracket denotes
coefficient extraction)

$$\left[\prod_{k=1}^m X_k^{q_k}\right]
\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{1-X_k} 
Z(S_n)\left(\sum_{k=1}^m  X_k\right).$$

The following  code implements this  formula using Maple.  The formula
can  be optimized  for particular  values of  the quantities  $q_k$ in
various ways e.g.  by

$$\text{replacing}\quad  1/(1-X_k) \quad\text{by}\quad
1+X_k+\cdots+X_k^{q_k}.$$

(In  fact numeric  experiments indicate  that  this is  not always  an
improvement.)

```
pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

V :=
proc(q, n)
local gf, m, vp;

    m := nops(q);

    gf := mul(1/(1-X[k]), k=1..m)*
    pet_varinto_cind(add(X[k], k=1..m),
                     pet_cycleind_symm(n));


    for vp to m do
        gf := coeftayl(gf, X[vp]=0, q[vp]);
    od;

    gf;
end;

W := n -> V([seq(n, q=1..n)], n);
```

A session with this code looks like this:

```
> V([3,3,3,3], 5);
                                       40

> V([3,3,3,4], 5);
                                       43

> V([5,5,5,5], 5);
                                       56
```

and we have confirmation of the values given by the OP.

Additional  verification may be  obtained by treating  the special
case of  $n$ products with max  capacity $q_k = n$  and $n$ customers.
Here we  do not  need the factor  in front  that we added  because the
cycle index itself enforces the limit of $n$ products of each type. We
thus get  the formula (all of whose  different multinomials contribute
one to the total):

$$\left. Z(S_n)\left(\sum_{k=1}^m  X_k\right)\right|_{X_k=1}$$

Now  recall the OGF of the multiset operator $\mathfrak{M}_{=n}$ which 
is
$$Z(S_n) = [z^n]
\exp\left(a_1 z + a_2 \frac{z^2}{2}
+ a_3 \frac{z^3}{3}
+ a_4 \frac{z^4}{4}
+\cdots \right).$$

On substituting into the cycle index we put
$$a_p = \left. \sum_{k=1}^m  X_k^p\right|_{X_k=1} = n$$
because we have $m=n$ in this special case.

This yields the formula
$$[z^n] \exp\left(n z + n \frac{z^2}{2}
+ n \frac{z^3}{3}
+ n \frac{z^4}{4}
+\cdots \right)
= [z^n] \exp\left(n\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^n}
= {2n-1\choose n-1}.$$

And indeed when we run the Maple code we obtain

```
> seq(W(n), n=1..18);
1, 3, 10, 35, 126, 462, 1716, 6435, 24310, 92378, 352716, 1352078,

    5200300, 20058300, 77558760, 300540195, 1166803110, 4537567650

> seq(binomial(2*n-1,n-1), n=1..18);
1, 3, 10, 35, 126, 462, 1716, 6435, 24310, 92378, 352716, 1352078,

    5200300, 20058300, 77558760, 300540195, 1166803110, 4537567650
```

This sequence is [OEIS A001700](http://oeis.org/A001700).

The  same computation works when  all quantities $q_k$  of the $m$
products are at least $n$ where it yields the binomial coefficient
$${n+m-1\choose m-1}$$ which appears to be an application of stars and bars.

**Remark.**   The  main   formula  above   correctly   represents  the
combinatorial givens  of this problem  but unlike in the  example just
presented  with $n$  products,  $n$ customers  and  capacity $n$  said
formula computes  all possible  multisets and hence  does not  yield a
reduction in complexity for the problem.

**Addendum.** We don't need the Polya Enumeration Theorem here. I will
leave the above for the curious to consult. The formula is of course

$$[z^n] \prod_{k=1}^m (1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{q_k}).$$

This yields for a uniform capacity $q$

$$[z^n] \prod_{k=1}^m \frac{1-z^{q+1}}{1-z}
= [z^n] \frac{(1-z^{q+1})^m}{(1-z)^m}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/(q+1)\rfloor}
{m\choose p} (-1)^p {m-1+n-p(q+1)\choose m-1}.$$

When $q\ge n$ only the term  for $p=0$ contributes and we get the same
formula as from the PET computation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem is [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma). Let $S_5$ be the group of permutations of the $5$ customers, and $X$ the set of all possible sales where the names of the customers matter. For $\sigma\in S_5$ let $X^\sigma$ be the subset of $X$ containing all sales that are not changed when $\sigma$ is applied to the customers involved. Burnside's lemma gives the number of *orbits* of $X$ under the action of $S_5,$ i.e., the number of classes of sales when the identity of the customers does not matter:

$$|X/S_5|=\frac1{|S_5|}\sum_{\sigma\in S_5}|X^\sigma|.$$

In order to count $|X^\sigma|$ we have to consider the decomposition of $\sigma$ in disjoint cycles. There are 7 possibilities:

1 cycle of length 5 (transitive permutation): a sale is invariant under $\sigma$ only if all 5 customers buy the same product. There are no such sales in your first two examples, and 4 such sales in the last example (one for each product). There are $4!=24$ such permutations.

1 cycle of length 4: a sale is invariant if 4 out of 5 customers buy the same product; there is no restriction on the 5th customer (she may also buy the same product or a different one). There are $5\times3!$ such permutations. In the last example each such permutation leaves $4\times 4$ sales invariant; but there are no such sales in your first example and only $4$ such sales in your second example.

1 cycle of length 3, 1 cycle of length 2: 20 permutations. In the last example each permutation leaves $4\times4$ sales invariant.

1 cycle of length 3, 2 fixed points: 20 permutations. In the last example each of them leaves $4^3$ sales invariant.

2 cycles of length 2: 15 permutations. In the last example each of them leaves $4^3$ sales invariant.

1 cycle of length 2, 3 fixed points (i.e., just swapping two customers): 10 permutations. In the last example each of them leaves $4^4$ sales invariant.

The identical permutation. It leaves all sales invariant (in the last example there are $4^5$ of those).

For the last example Burnside's lemma then gives

$$|X/S_5|=\frac1{120}(24.4+30.16+20.16+20.64+15.64+10.256+1024)=56.$$

In this example the number of sales left invariant is always a power of $4$ (the number of products) and the exponent is the number of disjoint cycles in the permutation. This is not always true in the other examples because there the supply of some or all products is less than the number of customers, e.g., the first of the seven categories leaves *zero* sales invariant because there is no way for all 5 customers to buy the same product.